# Datapower - Error Validation against XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm validating an XML file against an XSL (i dont want modify the XSL), but i'm getting this error:

> Error:
>
> Error on line 35 of ValFactura.xsl: XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching
>   1-argument function named
>   {http://www.datapower.com/extensions}variable() in built-in template
>   rule

JAVA Code:

```
   try {
            OutputStream os = new PrintStream(System.out);
            xsl.process(xmlFile, xslFile, os);
   } 
   catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }

private void process(Source xml, Source xsl, Result result) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            Templates template = factory.newTemplates(xsl);
            Transformer transformer = template.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(xml, result);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
            throw new TransformerException(tce.getMessageAndLocation());
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            throw new TransformerException(te.getMessageAndLocation());
        }
    }
```

XSL Extract:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" 
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" 
    version="1.0">
....
    <xsl:variable name="numeroRuc" select="substring(dp:variable('var://context/cpe/nombreArchivoEnviado'), 1, 11)"/>
....
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Maven Library:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
     <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
     <version>9.5.1-5</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: Sorry my bad english :=)

Comment: So in which enviroment do you want to use that stylesheet making use of IBM datapower specific extensions? Don't expect extensions to be portable between XSLT processors.

Comment: The development is mounted on Wildly, so I understand that I would have to mount my Websphere development?

Comment: The error message looks very much as if it comes from Saxon, and Saxon of course will not understand Datapower extension functions.